# Is it possible to copy image just with Ctrl+C in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I know how to get the selected text in javascript
But I'm curious about the possibility to get the seleted node's HTML
It seems that something like  `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer`
is not working for me?
e.g:
I select the **img** tag and I want to save it into the IndexDB or LocalStorage
But I have to get the img node before everything
Any ideas about it?Thanks

Comment: I would use a drag-select library like this: http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply perform this action on a click event?

```
var imageClickEvent = function () {
    var source = this.src;
    /* do something with the source... */
};
```